# Regarding Hue based Face detection OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have tried to implement face detection algo for people with wide range of skin color, in different illumination conditions (e.g. darkness, disco lights, sunny day). First thing that comes in mind is based on thresholding of Hue and Saturation as they are illumination invariant (as mentioned in many papers). But I this wont work when a person is illuminated by Blue or Red light. Moreover in darkness too it is not giving the result.

I also tried using Voila jones (HaarCascade for multiple face detection in OpenCV), but it also can not detect a lot of faces in normal light condition.

False detection throught HaarCascade method can be prevented by keeping a check of skin percentage. And to avoid missing the detection, I tried to find the skin portions first and then apply Voila jones in that region. But this too doesnt work.

Can anybody please suggest  what feature am I missing to consider for the face detection in different light conditions ?

Comment: just an idea but what if you were to desaturate the image into a 16bpp channel grayscale and then adjust the levels to get a decent dynamic range? (and then pass on to the face detection cascade)

Comment: But then, converting an image taken in dark or in a disc wont give me correct grey scale image in which I can detect a person right ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'in a disc'?

Comment: If it is taken in the dark and there is sufficent dynamic range in the image then you might be able to adjust the gain or the shadows/highlights to get a more uniform dynamic range (by trying to normalize the level histogram).  Not sure it will work - just an idea.  Hence this not being an answer

Comment: by disc i meant a place where there might be blue/green/red/ etc colored lights falling over a person's face.

Comment: Did you mean a disco?

Comment: Yes I meant disco only.